# Volley response String not comparing properly in if statement

Tags: java, android, string, android-volley

I am using Volley library with android and getting a response from my server as a String object but cant compare it correctly. I am trying the following:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://www...";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("from onResponse()", response);
        if(response.equals("no_such_table")){
            //do something
        }else{
            //do something else
        }
    }
},
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        onTaskFailed(error);
    }
})
```

The android monitor is printing out the expected string ("no_such_table"), yet the else case is being triggered. is there an issue with the encoding of the response returned from the server with the volley library?

I have also tried

```
response.toString().equals("no_such_table")

String.valueOf(response).equals("no_such_table")

"no_such_table".equals(response)

"no_such_table".equals(response.toString())
```

but I cant get it to work as expected

The response is given by the php script on the server as

```
$val = mysql_query('select 1 from `" . $device_group_id . "` LIMIT 1');
if($val == FALSE){
    //table does not exist so return message
    echo "no_such_table";
}
```

Comment: response will be generally in json format, its better to first parse it and then compare

Comment: ["looks" equal but they are not](http://ideone.com/Ff23Ip) or any other similar problems ...

Comment: Yeah I had thought about unwanted spaces but used replaceAll(" ", "") as the response shouldnt have any spaces and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem and I managed to solve it!
Try using the `.trim()` method with your string.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d("from onResponse()", response);
    response = response.trim();
    if(response.equals("no_such_table")){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. This worked. Do you know why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

first evaluate your response as:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

    if(response != null && response.equals("expected_string")){
        //print log of response when it isnt a null value
         Log.d("from onResponse()", "datas = " + response);
        //do something
    }else{
         Log.d("from onResponse()", "null response");
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
"expected_string".equals(response)
```

or

```
"expected_string".equals(response.toString())
```

Comment: The author stated in the question that this solution doesn't work for him as well

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d("from onResponse()", response);
    if(("expected_string").equals(response.toString())){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```